# How to load an html file in xCode project?

Tags: html, iframe, localhost

I am asking if it's possible to do something like this.

Design a web app in html5 or something, and then just load it in xcode from localhost.

If I can, how should I do it?

Consider that from 0/10 xcode knowledge, I have 0.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easy route would be to have the end-user create a weblink/shortcut to your localhost webapp URL. This assumes that full functionality is housed on the server-side and the client is only consuming/viewing the HTML.

The more dynamic answer would be to create an app in XCode and include a UIWebView. From there instantiate an NSURL and point it to "http://localhost/".